# Compiling GNU Guile 1.8.8 with msys2: Undefined reference to '_imp__scm_shell' and '_imp__scm_boot_guile'

Tags: undefined-reference, msys2, guile

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I was unable to find a question similar to mine on this site.

I am trying to compile GNU Guile 1.8.8 with msys2 on Windows, but am running into undefined reference errors to '_imp__scm_shell' and '_imp__scm_boot_guile'. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Install and update msys2-20170918
2. Install base-devel, mingw-w64-i686-toolchain, mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain, mingw-w64-i686-libtool, and mingw-w64-x86_64-libtool with pacman
3. Download GNU Guile 1.8.8
4. Open msys2\mingw32.exe and cd to the source code's directory
5. Run ./configure --disable-error-on-warning
6. Run make

After a few minutes, it exits with the following errors:

```
guile-guile.o: In function 'inner_main':
C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\guile-1.8.8\libguile/guile.c:53: undefined reference to '_imp__scm_shell'
guile-guile.o: In function 'main':
C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\guile-1.8.8\libguile/guile.c:63: undefined refencere to '_imp__scm_boot_guile'
```

Here is the log file, in case it is useful: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dUj8ThwZKYL1Haehq3LFu6QAzkbDqqYv

Information on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: A quick search shows a number of issues historically building guile for Windows.  That's likely especially true for a version that's 8 years old.

Comment: Even build scripts for recent versions apply a number of patches e.g. https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/guile

Comment: @Joe I see. I guess I'll have to concede defeat.

Comment: Or just find out what DLL is supposed to inplement `scm_boot_guile` and `scm_shell` and add linker flags to link in the static import library (.a) file for that DLL.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I have tried searching for one on my computer, and don't seem to have a dll file that mentions scm_boot_guile or scm_shell.

Answer (score 0):

[It is perfectly possible to build guile 1.8 in this environment](https://github.com/slowphil/mingw-w64-guile1.8), with a few patches, and only for 32 bits. There is even a binary package available.